# Convert SQL Server Script to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a 5800+ line SQL Server scripts that handles long, intricate calculations that was given to me by a client from their old developer. I don't have the know-how nor a solid environment to work with SQL Server (all of my machines at my studio are Linux-based, so are all my hosts).

I'm looking for a way to convert these scripts to MySQL, either by way of an automated tool, or by a grisly tutorial that should get me most of the way through it.

Any one have any ideas or experience with this?

Comment: If this script is for a business purpose and you don't really want errors in translation, please hire a consultant and save yourself trouble down the line

Comment: Why don't you post some of the sections that don't make sense to you as a mysql dev and we can explain what it does.  (Maybe it won't be as different as you think it will.)

Comment: I suspect this is a grisly task. The things that will give you difficulty are MS extensions to SQL or changes to syntax that MS have introduced. Of course their view of these things is that they are meeting standards - they just happen to be MS's interpretation and extension of the standard. I would agree with @Richard's comment, though I would not phrase it the same way - do consider buying in some serious expertise to help handle this conversion.

Comment: Of course, I expect that it is quite broken -- they are probably not intricate calculations just poorly implemented ones.

Comment: If it's not something that absolutely has to be done in a stored procedure, it may be better to move the logic out of the database and into a general-purpose programming language, where the tools for structuring code are much better. Doing intricate business logic in the database layer can be unpleasantly unmanageable.

Comment: @bobince I'm trying to just get the original formula in plain English from the first developer. I'd much prefer to do this all in RoR.

Comment: "I have a 5800+ line MSSQL script that handles long, intricate calculations that was given to me by a client from their old developer." - ask the Dev for his unit test scripts as well....A 5800 line intricate calculation needs verification and testing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pay someone to do it, or crank up a virtual machine with windows and sqlexpress which may take you considerable time and effort.

hell, you could even pay me to do it, if its worth the price :)

Comment: Ended up doing the virtual machine